# Error: $ operator not defined for this S4 class while running hoslem.test

Tags: r, logistic-regression, lasso-regression, goodness-of-fit

I'm working on an optimization of a logistic regression model made with `glm`, the optimization is a lasso regression using `glmnet`. I want to compare both models using the output of a Hosmer Lemeshow test and I get this output.
For the `glm` I get

```
> hl <- hoslem.test(trainingDatos$Exited, fitted(logit.Mod))
> hl

    Hosmer and Lemeshow goodness of fit (GOF) test

data:  trainingDatos$Exited, fitted(logit.Mod)
X-squared = 2.9161, df = 8, p-value = 0.9395
```

And when I try to run the test for the lasso regression I get

```
> hll <- hoslem.test(trainingDatos$Exited, fitted(lasso.model), g=10)
Error in cut.default(yhat, breaks = qq, include.lowest = TRUE) : 
  'x' must be numeric
```

I also tried to use the coefficients of the lasso regression to make it numeric and I get

```
> hll <- hoslem.test(trainingDatos$Exited, fitted(lasso.model$beta), g=10)
Error: $ operator not defined for this S4 class
```

But when I treat it as an S4

```
> hll <- hoslem.test(trainingDatos$Exited, fitted(lasso.model@beta), g=10)
Error in fitted(lasso.model@beta) : 
  trying to get slot "beta" from an object (class "lognet") that is not an S4 object
```

Any way to run the test for my lasso regression?
Here is my full code for the lasso regression, can't share the database right now sorry

```
    #Creation of Training Data Set
input_ones <- Datos[which(Datos$Exited == 1), ] #All 1s
input_zeros <- Datos[which(Datos$Exited == 0), ] #All 0s
set.seed(100) 
#Training 1s
input_ones_training_rows <- sample(1:nrow(input_ones), 0.7*nrow(input_ones)) 
#Training 0s
input_zeros_training_rows <- sample(1:nrow(input_zeros), 0.7*nrow(input_ones)) 
training_ones <- input_ones[input_ones_training_rows, ]
training_zeros <- input_zeros[input_zeros_training_rows, ]
trainingDatos <- rbind(training_ones, training_zeros) 
library(glmnet)
#Conversion of training data into matrix form
x <- model.matrix(Exited ~ CreditScore + Geography + Gender
                  + Age + Tenure + Balance + IsActiveMember
                  + EstimatedSalary, trainingDatos)[,-1]
#Defining numeric response variable
y <- trainingDatos$Exited
sed.seed(100) 
#Grid search to find best lambda
cv.lasso<-cv.glmnet(x, y, alpha = 1, family = "binomial")
#Creation of the model
lasso.model <- glmnet(x, y, alpha = 1, family = "binomial", 
                      lambda = cv.lasso$lambda.1se)
coef(cv.lasso, cv.lasso$lambda.1se)
#Now trying to run the test
library(ResourceSelection)
set.seed(12657)
hll <- hoslem.test(trainingDatos$Exited, fitted(lasso.model), g=10)#numeric value error
hll <- hoslem.test(trainingDatos$Exited, fitted(lasso.model$beta), g=10)#$ not defined for S4
hll <- hoslem.test(trainingDatos$Exited, fitted(lasso.model@beta), g=10)#saying that beta is nos S4
```

Comment: Hi and Welcome to SO! Can you share a [reproducible](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example) example of your problem?

Comment: Hi thank you! I have just added my code for the lasso regression right now but I can't post the dataset

Comment: The problem is that the `fitted` function is not properly defined for `glmnet` objects. I think you can use the `predict` function setting `newx = x` and `s = cv.lasso$lambda.1se` but it's difficut to test without any data. If that doesn't work I think that you should add  an example with simulated data.

Answer (score 0):

glmnet uses a unique predict() method for obtaining fitted values. As rightly mentioned, the errors came from using fitted(). Meanwhile, running such tests could be easier with the gofcat package. Supported objects are passed directly to the functions. Your glm model, for instance, goes hosmerlem(logit.Mod).